# sqlite local variable as table name

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to use a rawquery like this:

```
cursor = helper.getReadableDatabase().rawQuery(
            "select _id from  inAd where Name like '%"+str2+"%'",
            null);
```

My problem is, inAd is a local variable.
How can I use such a one as a table name?

Comment: Like this? "select _id from " + inAd + " where Name like '%"+str2+"%'",

Comment: Note, that your query has a huge potential for SQL Injection. Instead of concatenating `str2`, you should pass it as an argument in the following arguments array (where you currently pass `null`). Also if you want to use table nam from variable, then you have no other choice, you have to concatenate it, **BUT** you should escape it, for example `table;name` should become `"table;name"`, while `table"name` should become `"table""name"``, and so on...